# How to use 2 pickerview in same view

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I need to create 2 pickers in my app. I need to show categories and product's types in de same screen on iphone, the question is, it is possible?

Tks!

Comment: We'll be able to give you more directed help if you let us know [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com).

Comment: Tim, whatd o you want to know?
BR

Comment: `UIPickerView` has components. you could split pickerview into 2.

Comment: how do you want to display tge pickerviews side by side or one after other or on button click or something event.please elaborate

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that by taking two different objects of pickerview .Give tag to both and use delegate methods with use of tag.